# When is it necessary to use "von" with "dorther"?

Tags: adverb

I'm trying to figure out when it's necessary to use *von* with *dorther*?

When I search for it on [context.reverso.net](https://context.reverso.net/%C3%BCbersetzung/deutsch-polnisch/dorther) one of the examples is:

- Kämst du **dorther**, wüsstest du das.

[wortbedeutung.info](https://www.wortbedeutung.info/dorther/) also shows some examples without *von*:

- Meine Familie stammt **dorther**, meine Wurzeln liegen im Kosovo.

but when I look for more example on let's say [linguee.com](https://www.linguee.com/english-german/search?source=german&query=dorther), most of them are *von dorther*:

- Es wird im Ausland mehr abgesetzt als **von dorther** bezogen.
- **Von dorther** kommt die Rapperin Reminisce Smith, die sich ganz unverblümt [...]

Would you say it's generally better/worse to leave *von* out or is there a rule to that?

What bothers me even more is that the first example doesn't use *von* while the third one does. Even though both use *kommen* as their main verbs.

I'm mostly interested in the *gehobene Sprache*, not what the average *Herr Mustermann* would say.

Would it then be correct to say (I made this sentence up):

- Wenn du in den Keller gehst, bring mir dorther meinen Werkzeugkasten.

Answer (score 3):

There are basically three possibilities:

> **[dorther](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/dorther)** + **[kommen](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/kommen#kommen_(Deutsch))**
>
>   A: **Woher** bist du gekommen?
>
>   B: Ich bin **dorther** gekommen.
>
> **von [dort](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/dort#dort_(Deutsch))** + **kommen**
>
>   A: **Von wo** bist du gekommen?
>
>   B: Ich bin **von dort** gekommen.
>
> **(von) dort** + **[herkommen](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/herkommen)**
>
>   A: **(Von) wo** bist du hergekommen?
>
>   B: Ich bin **(von) dort** hergekommen.

I personally would omit the preposition *[von](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/von#von_(Deutsch))* when a verb with the prefix *[her-](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/her-)* is used. The pattern is similar with *[hin-](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/hin-)*words:

> **[dorthin](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/dorthin)** + **[gehen](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/gehen)**
>
>   A: **Wohin** bist du gegangen?
>
>   B: Ich bin **dorthin** gegangen.
>
> **nach dort** + **gehen**
>
>   A: **Nach wo** bist du gegangen?
>
>   B: Ich bin **nach dort** gegangen.
>
> **(nach) dort** + **[hingehen](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/hingehen)**
>
>   A: **(Nach) wo** bist du hingegangen?
>
>   B: Ich bin **(nach) dort** hingegangen.

Notice, how the adverb (*dorther* / *von dort*) parallels the interrogative word (*woher* / *von wo*). Apparently, the possibilities are getting more and more mixed up, even in example sentences that you find in dictionaries.

Comment: I was trying to use it in stentences so I like the idea with asking a question. This way it should be easier to find more verbs that are _compatible_ with _dorther_ though I doubt there are many. I was able to find it used only with _kommen_ and _stammen_ so far.